# Change detection in 2D data

Tags: binary-data, change-point

I have a 2D data set in which I wish to detect changes as a function of time.
The x-ordinate is detector position, and the y-ordinate is time. The z-ordinate is either 0 or 1, showing the absence or presence of a peak.

The data is:
[image: image showing data.]

Here, you can see a major change at y~25, with minor changes at y~5, 75 (amongst others).

Is there a statistical test that can give me a single value for each y-ordinate, to allow me to see changes in this value to identify transformations? I think that the statistic would need to worry about the position of each peak, as well as the total number of peaks.

In this particular dataset, there are 109 y-values and 2841 x-values, with 80 < 1's < 170 per y-value. Other datasets would be similar.

I'm sure that my lack of success so far is just due to a lack of (or incorrect) keywords to search.

The original z-ordinate was intensity, but there is a very wide spread (~4 orders of magnitude) in intensity, and so other tests I've done don't pick up the little peaks and trigger the detection of a change. ie Jarque-Bera test - see Rajiv et al, Powder Diffr. 2009 24(1):8-16

Comment: The change in your case is at particular point in time one detector starts to lose the signal and the another picks it up? Are the detectors independent? What is the nature of the process that makes detectors switch on or off?

Comment: @mpiktas The change is with time going up the image. This is diffraction data, and the mix of phases is heated, and they react, changing their structure, and hence their diffraction peaks. The detectors are always on, and they detect intensity.

Comment: @mpiktas Pressed enter too soon:. 

The detectors can be considered to by independent in the x-direction. At a particular x-value, the same detector is used for all y-values.


This data was made by running a peak detection algorithm over the original intensity data to synthesise 1 or 0 data - peak present or absent. It holds no intensity information, only the fact that a peak was found; I'm trying to get around the factor that large variations in intensity had on the change detection previously.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is 2D data.  You have multiple time series and you either want to detect a change in each one individually, changepoint detection, or you want to detect changes that are common across several (maybe not all) series, multivariate changepoint detection.

Comment: @adunaic This is where I'm running into difficulty searching for answers. At a particular time, $t$, I have a certain distribution of peaks, $P(t)$ (Note that peaks are either present or not). At time $t+1$ I have another distribution of peaks, $P(t+1)$. I want to know when $P(t)$ is significantly different to $P(t+1)$.

If you take one time-series to be a single x-value, then I have 2841 time-series. If this is the case, then I want to detect changes common across several (the majority, some large fraction of...) series.